# Firebase withCompletionBlock not called if there is no connection

Tags: ios, firebase

I am using the following:

```
Firebase *fb =[[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:url];
            [fb setValue:d withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, Firebase *ref) {
                if (error) {
                    // bad news
                } else {

                }
            }];
```

This seems to work great IF you have a connection, if not it seems the callback is never called.  If that is the case do I then need to wrap this whole thing in a `connectedRef`?  Seems like alot of extra work when I would guess the completion block would just fail with an error status of not online.

Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: I believe that when Firebase starts in offline mode, you need to call a `set` op with value null. I'm not firm on the details here, but that should kick off the init. Also, full offline persistence was added in the latest release: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/dOocEtjQz4w

Comment: That is a technique to get your observers to fire events when you're not online.  The observer won't fire unless it has data from the server or from a local setValue call, so sometimes it makes sense to do a setValue to get the observers to fire.  But you won't usually need this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea behind Firebase is it synchronizes data for you.  It's more than just a simple request / response system.  So if you do a setValue while offline, Firebase will hold onto that data until you *are* online, and then it'll do the setValue at that time (and then the completion block will be called).

So the behavior you're seeing is expected.  If you only want to do the setValue if you're online, then yes, you'll need to use a .info/connected observer.  But you could still run into issues if for instance you go offline at the moment you try to do the setValue or something along those lines.  In general it's better to just do the setValue and let Firebase take care of it for you.

Comment: Michael, is this behaviour consistent across all platforms? I thought the moment you call set API in javascript, the local callback is called immediately even if you are offline.

Comment: We might be talking about different things.  The event callbacks (i.e. registered with .on) are called immediately on a set() call, but the set() onComplete callback won't be called until the set makes it to the server.  This should be consistent across all platforms.

Comment: The values are updated to the server once connect resumes but the completion blocks are not called.